# What is use of flex Enter frame

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How and when to use `obj.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,fun)` enter frame event? I dont understand how to use it on displayobjects or UIcomponents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ENTER_FRAME gets fired each time when the stage is rendered. In example, if you would want to move an object across the stage, you could do something like this:

```
// Your Sprite
mySprite.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveIt);

function moveIt(e:Event):void{
    e.currentTarget.x += 1;
}
```

Just as a small example.

Comment: A frame is nothing visual. When running a flash/flex application, you set a framerate at which the whole project is rendered. If you set the framerate to 30, the whole stage will be rendered 30 Times per second. This updates the visual elements on screen.

Comment: @checkmate As an answer to "when to use ENTER_FRAME in a Flex app": never (unless you have a very specific requirement or a game on your hands). Look at it as a more low-level ActionScript Event: the Flex framework uses it a lot for rendering and animation, but abstracts the complexities away.